# Combine or Intersect Multiple MySQL Commands

Tags: php, mysql, sql, inner-join, intersect

I have to search on two tables.

My second table is:

```
+---------+---------------+-------+
| user_id | is_first_time | score |
+---------+---------------+-------+
|   44    |       1       |   20  |
+---------+---------------+-------+
|   44    |       0       |   20  |
+---------+---------------+-------+
```

My first table just contains the user information.

- If I use the following MySQL command, I will get a result:

  ```
  SELECT * , users_score.user_id users_score_user_id 
  FROM users JOIN users_score 
  ON users_score.user_id = users.id 
  WHERE (users_score.score='20' AND users_score.is_first_time='1')
  ```
- If I use the following MySQL command, I will also get a result (I just change the "is_first_time" value to "0":

  ```
  SELECT * , users_score.user_id users_score_user_id 
  FROM users JOIN users_score 
  ON users_score.user_id = users.id 
  WHERE (users_score.score='20' AND users_score.is_first_time='0')
  ```
- But if I combine both commands with AND, I will not get any results:

  ```
  SELECT * , users_score.user_id users_score_user_id 
  FROM users JOIN users_score 
  ON users_score.user_id = users.id 
  WHERE (users_score.score='20' AND users_score.is_first_time='1')
  AND (users_score.score='20' AND users_score.is_first_time='0')
  ```

How can I combine or intersect both commands?

Thanks for any help.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

If you want users where both conditions are true, then one method uses `in` or `exists`:

```
SELECT u.* 
FROM users u
WHERE u.id IN (SELECT us.user_id FROM users_score us WHERE us.score = '20' AND us.is_first_time = '0'
              ) AND
      u.id IN (SELECT us.user_id FROM users_score us WHERE us.score = '20' AND us.is_first_time = '1'
              );
```

The issue with `AND` is that a single row cannot be both 0 and 1.

If you just want the users id, I would recommend `group by` and `having`:

```
select us.user_id
from users_score us
where score = 20 and us.is_first_time in (0, 1)
group by us.user_id
having count(distinct us.is_first_time) = 2;
```

Note that I removed the single quotes.  If columns are numbers, then don't use single quotes for comparisons.  (Of course, if they are strings, then use the single quotes.)

Answer (score 1):

You need to use `OR` condition here

```
WHERE (users_score.score='20' AND users_score.is_first_time='1') 
  OR  (users_score.score='20' AND users_score.is_first_time='0')
```

But it can be written in a better way using `IN` condition

```
SELECT *,
       users_score.user_id users_score_user_id
FROM   users
       JOIN users_score
         ON users_score.user_id = users.id
WHERE  users_score.score = '20'
       AND users_score.is_first_time IN ( '1', '0' )
```

Comment: Thanks for your reply. OR will get the rows with "is_first_time = 1", the rows with "is_first_time = 0" and the rows with "is_first_time = 1 and 0". So instead of getting one user id, it will get three. I think Gordon Linoff's answer is more correct. Thanks anyway.